# Beginner issue makefile won't work

Tags: c++, makefile

I swear I've been looking around for 20 min trying to figure this out and I know it has to be something incredibly simple. I'm trying to create a makefile for a couple of c++ compression programs I wrote. Here is the makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS =
ENC_SOURCES=encoderMain.cpp encoderUtils.cpp
DEC_SOURCES=decoderMain.cpp decoderUtils.cpp
ENC_OBJECTS=$(ENC_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEC_OBJECTS=$(DEC_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
ENC_EXECUTABLE=encoder

all: $(ENC_SOURCES) $(ENC_EXECUTABLE)

$(ENC_EXECUTABLE): $(ENC_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -O $@
```

I haven't added the decoder section yet but am just trying to get the encoder program to work. When I type in "make" into the command line, I receive this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've tried running the ./configure command and get this error:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I'm running on OS X Mavericks if that makes a difference. Thanks!

NOTE: the name of makefile is "makefile" I wrote it in a text editor so I believe it is actually makefile.txt.

Comment: Did you name the file Makefile? Is it in the same directory as where you're entering the command? ./configure will not work if you haven't setup the proper config scripts

Comment: What is the name of your make file?

Comment: I named the file "makefile". And yes, I tried running the make command in the same directory as the makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file name to `Makefile` and it should find it. (Remove the `.txt`)